# select the data which is within the next 6 months

Tags: laravel, eloquent

```
$medicines = Medicine::orderBy('exp_date','desc')
 ->where('exp_date','>', Carbon::now()->addmonths(6))
 ->paginate(15);
```

I am trying to select the data which is within the nxt 6 mths
but it is showing me the data after 6 mth

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
whereBetween('exp_date',Carbon:now(),Carbon:now()->addmonths(6))
```

So:

```
$medicines = Medicine::orderBy('exp_date','desc')->whereBetween('exp_date',Carbon:now(),Carbon:now()->addmonths(6))
 ->paginate(15);
```

There is a full post even disussing performance here [Retrieve Models between two dates](https://dev.to/nicolus/how-to-properly-retrieve-laravel-models-between-two-dates-1bek)